# How to declare C style arrays in objective-c app?

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays

I have two NSArrays, one of CLLocation and one of doubles (encased in objects) that I need to write to C vectors to draw a gradient MKPolyline as defined here (https://github.com/wdanxna/GradientPolyline). I tried to copy some of the code I saw there in preparation to call one of its functions:

```
points = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D)*self.run.locations.array.count);
velocity = malloc(sizeof(float)*self.run.locations.array.count);

for(int i = 0; i<self.run.locations.array.count; i++){
    points[i] = self.run.locations.array[i];
    velocity[i] = [velocities[i] floatValue];
}
```

Here self.run.locations.array is an array of `CLLocations`.

Right now I can't even build the project because I have not declared the variables. But where/how do I declare these variables? I don't know C, and the project I am trying to use doesn't seem to include these declarations in a place I can find them.

Comment: Well, did you declare points and velocity?

Comment: (If that's not clear, the "use of undeclared identifier" is your compiler's polite way of saying "wtf is `points`? Where does it come from? What's its type? Where does it live?")

Comment: This question has nothing to do with `malloc()`.  You appear to not know how to declare variables.  Did you read about Objective-C before jumping in and writing code?

Comment: @Mat Thanks for pointing this out. I don't know any C, and looking at the sample project I referenced and that I'm trying to use, I actually don't see where the original author declared either of these two variables. Where/how should they be declared?

Comment: @trojanfoe I learned Objective-C doing tutorials about how to build specific apps. I don't have any C programming experience. What exactly do you recommend I do that wouldn't involve months of study when I'm just trying to develop a simple app? For that matter if you have a reference other than the apple docs (which are enormous and dense) that you'd recommend to a beginner to better understand objective C architecture, I'm all ears, but I don't have hours a day to devote to this either. What is your idea of what I should have read before I started coding simple apps? I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: As far as I know Objective-C has the same requirements as C as far as declaring variables (and functions, and structs, etc.). You say "run.localtions.array is an array of CLLocations" - how does your compiler know that? Where did you write in your code that that was the case?

Comment: @mat Locations is an array of ordered many-to-one coordinate points that pairs with a Run ...both of these were created in Xcode making the classes based on a Core Data model. I've been doing some objective c programming on and off for about 6 months, and what I still find confounding is when something like automagically generating core data classes runs into the need for malloc-ing a C style array. I am out of my depth and often feel like I'm missing something in the leap back and forth between these tasks. I own 4 objective-c books, and none gets at this. Is every app maker a C programmer?

Comment: @trojanfoe I'm disappointed. I don't want to be snippy but you just made a snide remark about my ignorance and then ignore my question about what exactly it was that I should have read but didn't. Like I said I have read 4 books of tutorials about objective c. You have to admit that's more than enough to code up lots of little apps. What exactly is the next step in your opinion? I'm all ears, but you don't actually offer useful criticism here.

Comment: I ignored your question as I was not online. Declaring variables is common to both C and Objective-C (and almost every other language) and not knowing that indicated to me that you had just jumped right in and not studied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`points` is an array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D` (dynamically allocated) so it should be a pointer to `CLLocationCoordinate2D` i.e.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D *points;
```

`velocity` is an array of `float` so it should be declared as

```
float *velocity;
```

Alternatively you can do this

```
float velocity[];
```

if you prefer array syntax.